# How do I use AD Authentication in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, authorization

I want to know how to use Active Directory in the Account/Login.aspx page in my project but I cannot find a lot of resources out there for this.  I am using VS.Net 2013 Asp.net C# 4.0.  I have never had to do this before and I was just wondering how you access Active Directory and on a group level so only the person(s) that are in this group have access to the application.  Please anyone with a link or any information that would be great.  I am really stuck on this and I need to be able to have this working.

Comment: You can turn on NTLM authentication and do it that way,  http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/asp-net-windows-authentication-authorization-by-ntlm-group-2/

Comment: That's not going to work with the built in Login Page in the project under Account/Login.aspx.  I need to know how to work with the membership provider and the role manager to configure this the correct way.  I have tried multiple ways and the only thing I can do is get this to work on the User level but not on the Group level.  Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 6):

I use active directory and forms authentication. You can use this with the default Account/Login.aspx. These are the links that I have used to set it up.

[This link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316748) will show you how to log in with Active Directory.
[This link](http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html) will show you how to set up an ADRoleProvider.

I prefer to use them both because the first link will show you how to get the AD groups of the logged in user, but it saves them to an authentication cookie. You will have to decrypt this cookie to see which group the ad user is in... this can be a hassle.

The 2nd link will show you have to use roles, which is much simpler.

You can have a simple if statement like..

```
if(User.IsUserInRole("SoftDev"))
{
    //do something
}
```

or you use the roles in the web config like this..

```
<location path="Account/Whatever.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="SoftDev"/>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

this will deny everyone to that page besides the group "SoftDev"

Both these links are meant if you are using Forms Authentication as there are other articles out there for using Windows Authentication. I hope this helps.