# Implementing Azure AD authentication in web form application

Tags: webforms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an web application created on web form .net 4 (classic). It uses the asp.net membership and session for user authentication.

Now we want to take this app to azure and want to use the Azure AD authentication. I read the below document and found that it can be achieved and went through the steps. But I do have a question.   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/

If the application is enabled to use Azure AD Authentication to login and logout. How the aspx page would be verified for authorization.

In MVC we can add the [Authorize] attribute on the controller level or on the action. How I can translate into aspx page.

Comment: Do you have access to the IIS portal?

Comment: No, I don't .  The app would be deployed in App Service. After the application updated with Azure AD authentication.

Comment: Dang .. could use that, but not if you don't have access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you can use roles to direct to the aspx page.
something like :

```
if(User.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
{
    //do something
}
```

or try Configure web config like this.

```
<location path="Account/<pagename>.aspx">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

</location>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101006/how-do-i-use-ad-authentication-in-asp-net)